# How can i modify a db connection for a specific testmethod in a Django TestCase (and then restore upon completion)?

Tags: django, python-unittest

I have a special case where i need to run certain testmethods against one database and other testmethods against another **while maintaining the same alias** (within a given TestCase).

I am not asking about multiple db connections, the issue is changing a db connection for a given alias within a testmethod, and then reverting it back to the default state after the test method executes.

I have tried the following (this code is placed within my TestCase):

```
from django.db import connections
from django.db.backends.postgresql.base import DatabaseWrapper

def testSwitchDBParamsForAlias(self):
    db_wrapper = DatabaseWrapper(
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'HOST' : 'host',
        'PORT' : '2342',
        'NAME' : 'dbname',
        'USER' : 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'password'
    )
    connections.__setitem__('dbalias', db_wrapper)
    print(connections._databases) # This still has the old connection
```

In the code above, 'dbAlias' already exists with different credentials and im trying to swap the credentials out using the **setitem** method.

Another attempt using the context manager:

```
def testSwitchDBParamsUsingCM(self):
    with self.settings(DATABASES = DATABASES):
        # call setup_databases here
        print(connections._databases)  #old credentials printed here
```

A third approach:

```
def testSwitchDB(self):
    connections = ConnectionHandler(LAKE_TEST_DB)
    print(connections._databases)
    response = self.client.get(reverse('my_url'), format='json')
```

The third approach will actually modify the connections object! However this still does not work since in every api call (or view) the connections object is imported again and this change is overriden. So without modifying the API code, this method will also fail.

Neither works and I am left not understanding how this connection object works at all. Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be useful for you: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/multi-db/#manually-selecting-a-database

As long as you register both databases in your settings file, you should be able to route specific requests to either database with the using() method.

Comment: Thank you Brady, you are a Django master